# repaint query in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, repaint

I am an inexperienced (unless you count PDP-8s in the early '70s) programmer struggling with the repaint method in the enclosed Class.

The Class is intended to display an aviation map of the local area and then paint small circles onto the map to plot the passage of aircraft. Over time the map will show the most used paths followed by aircraft landing at the local airfield.

Problem is that after a days effort I still can't make repaint work.

The Class concerned with the Graphics is:

```
package com.slatter.radarboxconnect;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
* A RADAR Plotting Frame 
*/
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

    public static BufferedImage img = null; // Create a BufferedImage object
    public int cx = 700,cy = 500,cdia = 70; // Aircraft Echo parameters

    public DrawPanel() {

        // Create Graphic of map
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("full.jpeg"));  //Get the map
        } catch (IOException e){
        }
    }

    @Override 
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        //Draw the Map and a sample red dot
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 1400, 1000, 0, 0, 1400, 1000, null);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawOval(cx,cy, cdia, cdia);
        g.fillOval(cx,cy, cdia, cdia);
    }

    public void DpPlotEcho(int x, int y, int pdia) {

         cx=x;
         cy=y;
         cdia=pdia;
         repaint(cx,cy,cdia,cdia);
    }

}
```

I create this Panel in a separate Frame and call the DpPlotEcho() method from the main body of the App.

The map and a small red dot in the centre of the screen appear correctly but no updates occur with the attempt to repaint through the DpPlotEcho() method.

So two questions:

1. How do I persuade the repaint to work (The main issue) and
2. How do I make sure that all the dots stay on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I persuade the repaint to work (The main issue)

Every time you change the data you want to be painted for the component you just invoke repaint() on the component. Then the paintComponent() method will repaint the entire component.

> How do I make sure that all the dots stay on the screen.

You need to repaint all the circles every time the paintComponent() method gets invoked.

This is typcially done by:

1. Keeping an ArrayList of all the circle you want to paint and then just iterate through the list
2. Paint each circle onto a BufferedImage and then just paint the image.

See [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for an example of each approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try [repaint()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29) without arguments, `repaint(int x, int y, int width, int height)` repaints only a specified rectangle of the component.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try adding a new function:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 1400, 1000, 0, 0, 1400, 1000, null);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawOval(cx,cy, cdia, cdia);
    g.fillOval(cx,cy, cdia, cdia);
}
```

This is what I always do, and it works for me.